# How to calculate the total distance between various vertices in a graph?

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, graph-theory, depth-first-search

Let's say I have a weighted, undirected, acyclic graph with no negative value weights, comprised of n vertices and n-1 edges. If I want to calculate the total distance between every single one of them (using edge weight) and then add it up, which algorithm should I use? If for example a graph has 4 vertices, connected like a-b, a-c, c-d then the program should output the total distance needed to go from a-d, a-c, a-b, b-c, b-d and so on. You could call it every possible path between the given vertices. The language I am using is C++.

I have tried using Dijikstra's and Prim's algorithm, but none have worked for me. I have thought about using normal or multisource DFS, but I have been struggling with it for some time now. Is there really a fast way to calculate it, or have I misunderstood the problem entirely?

Comment: What is a **non-circular** graph?

Comment: @DavidGrayson A mistake I made. I meant acyclic. Fixed it.

Comment: `a-d, a-c, a-b, b-c, b-d`: is that not at least 4 vertices?

Comment: Dijkstra's algorithm, being run separately from every vertex, should work just fine. As would Floyd-Warshall or Bellman-Ford. Note that the graph you describe is a _tree_, and there sure is a more efficient way. Nevertheless, Dijkstra's algorithm should work, so you might want to get that straight first.

Comment: @chrslg correct. Excuse me for a typo.

Comment: @Gassa I actually thought about treating it as a tree, but I got confused by how should I treat the 'distance' between two vertices, measured here by edge weight. I even thought about using centroid decomposition, but I think the distances would get messed up that way.

Comment: If the graph is acyclic and undirected that means there is only one path that links two points, right ? So you wouldn't need to find the minimum path/cost here... I suggest you implement a depth first approach combined with memoization to reduce time complexity.

Comment: Where is the code that shows what you have tried?

Comment: @Gassa The time complexity would be n^2 log n, since dijikstra takes nlogn time to solve, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have an acyclic graph, there is only one possible path between any two points.  This makes things a lot simpler to compute and you don't need to use any real pathfinding algorithms.

Let's say we have an edge E that connects nodes A and B.  Calculate how many nodes can be reached from node A, not using edge E (including A).  Multiply that by the number of nodes that can be reached from node B, not using edge E (including B).  Now you have the number of paths that travel through edge E.  Multiply this by the weight of edge E, and you have the total contribution of edge E to the sum.

Do the same thing for every edge and add up the results.

To make the algorithm more efficient, each edge can store cached values that say the number of nodes that are reachable on each side of the edge.

You don't have to use a depth first search.  Here is some pseudocode showing how you calculate the number of nodes reachable on a side of edge E very fast taking advantage of caching:

```
int count_nodes_reachable_on_edge_side(Edge e, Node a) {
  // assume edge e directly connects to node a
  if (answer is already cached in e) { return the answer; }
  
  answer = 1;  // a is reachable
  for each edge f connected to node a {
    if (f is not e) {
      let b be other node f touches (not a)
      answer += count_nodes_reachable_on_edge_side(f, b)
    }
  }

  cache the answer in edge e;
  return answer;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. How would I go about all this? By using dfs? Wouldn't the time complexity skyrocket from this?

Comment: There is no need for any real pathfinding algorithm.  I added pseudo code to the answer above.

Comment: Ok, and how to do a for each node connected to node a? Should I use an adjacency matrix for this, or create a graph class with a function that will return nodes connected to it?

Comment: I assume you already have some reasonable data structure for representing the graph, the nodes, and the edges because you have been writing a lot of code that does graph stuff.  I don't really care what data structure you use as long as you can get information from it quickly, and you can store two cached integers for each edge.

Comment: I feel like you're overthinking this and just throwing around lots of technical jargon hoping it will be relevant.  This problem is quite simple and I've already given the complete algorithm and I didn't have to use any of those things.  (Since you're already storing the weight of each edge, just add two more integers next to the weight.)

Comment: Hm, perhaps you're right. I guess I just got lost in the implementation. Sorry.

Comment: I fixed the code.  The answer must be initialized to 1 because node `a` is reachable.

Comment: Would this work for the sum of a part of vertices? For example, in the graph that I mentioned in the post, if I wanted to calculate the sum of distances between only ab, and bc, would I just need to use the method you mentioned different amount of times?

Comment: You'd also want to calculate the distance from a to c, right?  You can modify it to work like that.  On the line that says `answer = 1` you would change that to set answer to 1 if the node a is in the subset of nodes you care about reaching, and 0 otherwise.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I just want to know what Big O is in this. Is it O(k * N) where k is the number of vertices we want to 'sum'  and N is the number of total vertices?

Comment: Let's see.  If N is the number of nodes, the number of edges if N - 1.  I can convince myself the run time is O(N\*N) because the algorithm iterates over each edge (and there are O(N) edges) and then for each edge there is a loop that considers a subset of the edges, and the number of edges in that subset is O(N).  (Using a subset of the vertices doesn't affect the run time so we might as well just stick to the original problem and assume k == N.)  You can't have a tighter bound that O(N\*N) because if all the edges are connected to a single central node, my algorithm is quadratic.

Comment: I think there is a slightly smarter algorithm that is O(N) but we are getting beyond the scope of the original question, which I already answered.  Please accept my answer and consider asking another question if you specifically want O(N).

Comment: Ok, I accepted your answer since it answers my problem, but if you don't mind of course, could you elaborate a bit more on how could I implement this algorithm in practice? I'm still a big newbie when it comes to graphs, so I'm having trouble grasphing all of this.

Comment: That's a little too broad follow up question you have there .  I gave a very precise algorithm in pseudo code so all you have to do is convert it to C++ one line at a time.  I recommend that you try writing the code yourself and *if* you have trouble, post a [mcve] along with the expected output and actual output.  That's the best way to use Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

I already presented an O(N^2) algorithm in my other answer, but I think you can actually do this in O(N) time with this pseudo code:

```
let root be an arbitrary node on the graph;
let total_count be the total number of nodes;
let total_cost be 0;

process(root, null);

// Returns the number of nodes reachable from node n without going
// through edge p.  Also adds to total_cost the contribution from
// all edges touching node n, except for edge p.
int process(Node n, Edge p)
{
  count = 1
  for each edge q that touches node n {
    if (q != p) {
      let m be the other node connected to q (not n)
      sub_count = process(m, q)
      total_cost += weight(q) * sub_count * (total_count - sub_count)
      count += sub_count
    }
  }
  return count
}
```

The run time of this is O(N), where N is the number of nodes, because `process` will be called exactly once for each node.

(For the detail-oriented readers: the loop inside `process` does not matter: there are O(N) iterations that call `process`, because `process` is called on each node exactly once.  There are O(N) iterations that don't do anything (because `q == p`), because those iterations can only happen once for `process` call.)

Every edge will also be visited.  After we recursively count the number of nodes on one side of the edge, we can do a simple subtraction (`total_count - sub_count`) to get the number of nodes on the other side of the edge.  When we have these two node counts, we can just multiply them together to get the total number of paths going through the edge, then mulitply that by the weight, and add it to the total cost.